# Linq find all elements from nested list which have id

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core

I have the following classes:

```
public class AssignmentDetails : EntityBase
    {
        public DateTime StartingTime { get; protected set; }
        public DateTime EndingTime { get; protected set; }
        public ICollection<AssignedUser> AssignedUsers { get; protected set;}
        public Assignment Assigment { get; protected set; }
        public int AssigmentId { get; protected set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; protected set; }
        public User Owner { get; protected set; }
        public State State { get; protected set; }
        public AssignmentDetails(DateTime startingTime,DateTime endingTime,int ownerId,State state,ICollection<AssignedUser> assignedUsers)
        {
            AssignedUsers = assignedUsers;
            StartingTime = startingTime;
            EndingTime = endingTime;
            OwnerId = ownerId;
            State = state;
        }
        public AssignmentDetails() { }
    }

 public class Assignment : EntityBase
    {
        public string Title { get; protected set; }
        public AssignmentDetails AssignmentDetails { get; protected set; }
        public string Description { get; protected set; }
        public int ParentAssignmentId { get; protected set; }
        public Assignment(string title,string description,AssignmentDetails assignmentDetails)
        {
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
            AssignmentDetails = assignmentDetails;
        }
        public void AddParentAssignment(int parentAssignmentId)
        {
            ParentAssignmentId = parentAssignmentId;
        }
        public Assignment(){ }
    }

 public class AssignedUser : EntityBase
    {
        public AssignmentDetails Assignment { get; protected set; }
        public int AssignmentDetailsId { get; protected set; }
        public int UserId { get; protected set; }
        public AssignedUser(int userId)
        {
            UserId = userId;
        }
        public AssignedUser() { }
    }
```

I need to find the all assignments for a particular user which is Owner of a assignment, or is assigned in AssignedUsers

I tried the following and some other alternatives but looks like i catch my ears somewhere.

```
public async Task<List<Assignment>> GetAllAsignmentsAsync(int userId)
    {
        return await _context.Assignments
            .Include(a => a.AssignmentDetails)
            .Where(x => x.AssignmentDetails.OwnerId == userId || x.AssignmentDetails.AssignedUsers.SelectMany(u=> u.UserId== userId))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    .Where(x => x.AssignmentDetails.OwnerId == userId 
|| x.AssignmentDetails.AssignedUsers.Any(u=> u.UserId== userId))
```

Use `Any` to return `true` or `false` condition. `SelectMany` selects some objects based on condition(s)

Comment: But in this case Any will return always true if in that list exists an element which contains userId, right ? I would like to select only the Assignments which have Assignment.AssignmentDetails.AssignedUser.UserId == userId

Comment: @Spoukey, that's exactly what `Any` will do